# How to "Discard Line" in GitKraken?

Tags: git, gitkraken

Line can be easy staged with the plus button "Stage this line".

There are "Discard Hunk" and "Stage Hunk" symbols.

But how to "Discard Line"? Is there any shortcurt how to change the plus button right next to the line to minus button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can right click on the line you would like to discard, and select 'discard this line' in the context menu that pops up.

Comment: What version? I'm not seeing this in 6.0.0 (osx), at least not for deleted lines.

Comment: @cdunham I was using 5.0.4 on mojave, and just upgraded to 6.0.0 and the context menu are there in both versions, but only for modified files. New files and deleted files don't have a context menu with 'Disgard this line' option. If you want to keep a deleted file, you can right click on the file name on the top section of right panel and select 'Discard changes'

Comment: Thanks, @JoYSword. So the use case for me is that I've edited a file a bunch, but now I want to restore some lines I've deleted. In SourceTree, this is pretty easy: select some lines and the "discard hunk" button changes to "discard lines". SourceTree has some major failings, but it does this one thing really well.

Comment: @GrantCurell just checked on version 6.0.1 on macOS. Still valid, as long as the file is not a new file but a modified one, and you're right clicking an added line (with green background)

Comment: This is getting really frustrating. I keep having to jump through hoops (or start SourceTree) just to handle these cases!

Comment: @cdunham same problem - i think it doesn'T work in 'hunk view' - you have to go to 'split view'

Comment: So things are definitely better in split view, but the issue remains (even in 7.0.0). If you change a single line, you cannot stage (or discard) only one of the before/after versions as you can in SourceTree, GitX, and other tools. It insists on taking them both together.

Comment: The key for me was @JoYSword's comment. It only works on modified files and not new ones. I was trying to discard a line on a new file, but obviously since everything there is new it is technically not discarding anything which is why it doesn't show the option.